# I want add seek forward and seek rewind buttons in flowplayer for video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flowplayer

I am  using flowplayer and I setup the video by this way and I added 2 buttons for fastFwd and rewind

```
  <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flow/flowplayer.swf">
      <video id="myvideo" class="myvideo">
        <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
      </video>
    </div>
    <div> <a id="fastFwd" onClick="seek();return false;">fastFwd</a> 
    <a id="rewind" onClick="seek();return false;">rewind</a>
    </div>


   <script>
      $("#forward, #rewind").click(function (seek) {
          if (api.ready) {
            var target = $(this).attr("myvideo") == "forward" ? 5 : -5;
            api.seek(api.video.time + target);
          }
        });
    </script>


 But the buttons doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ID's are not correct. Either you'll need to change your HTML to have the same ID's in your jquery, or change the ones in your jquery to have the same ones in your HTML.

```
<script>
  $("#fastFwd, #rewind").click(function (seek) {
      if (api.ready) {
        var target = $(this).attr("myvideo") == "forward" ? 5 : -5;
        api.seek(api.video.time + target);
      }
    });
</script>
```